# Legendre polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I'm relatively new here( This is my first question tbh)
This question is from my assignment which I'm supposed to submit in two days. I have been scratching my head over past couple of days but have reached nowhere.

> Obtain the first three terms in the expansion of  function F(x) in a series of the form
>   $$
> F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k P_k(x)
> $$
>   where
>   $$F(x)=\{\cos(x) \text{ for } 0 \le x \le \pi/2 \
> $$$$0 \text{ for } \frac{\pi}{2} \le x \le \pi.\}
> $$

What I know is I have to use legendre's expansion formula
i.e,$F(x) =\sum A_kP_k(x)$ where $-1≤x≤1$
But obviously I cannot use it directly because the range of $x$ differs. I have tried substituting $x=\cos(\theta)$ but no success so far.

P.S Please don't downvote, and instead suggest where I must improve. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, I hope you stay to contribute to the site! Here is a MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable help! Will stay and contribute surely

Comment: I do not understand your definition of $F(x):$ Is it $\cos x$ on the whole interval
$[0, \pi]$ or is there something mission before **'or for ...'.**? You can use an affine ('linear') transformation, $u=a + bx$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. The last edit messed it and didn't notice!

Comment: Hi @gammatester, I have, with much pain, corrected my previous mistakes. Thank you. Do point if there is anythingr else wrong or missing.

Comment: The differing ranges $0\le x\le \pi$ and $-1\le x\le 1$ is troubling. Despite this, $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and is defined for all $x$. The trouble is that to use the orthogonality of $P_n(x)$ you need to integrate on the interval $-1\le x\le 1$. Please double check your question source to determine the source of the discrepancy.

Comment: I did. It's the same. And it's the range that is bugging me too